# Azure Notification Hub example to register a device and receive a notification

Tags: c#, azure, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I am looking for a Azure Notification Hub example
- to register a device (get the token)
- and receive a notification (by the token form the register process)

Do any one have a practical example in C# or node.js ? where it is posible to configure the hubName and accessSignature to get it work

I have configured my azure notification hub with a google fcm

Answer (score 2):

You can go through the following documentation to understand [`Registration management`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management)

```
var hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("{connectionString}", "hubName");

// create a registration description object of the correct type, e.g.
var reg = new WindowsRegistrationDescription(channelUri, tags);
```

Comment: which project-type and net-framework do you use for the example in the documenation ?

Comment: the above one is c#, but you can do with any language https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The ionic3 example on this git archiv is not useable.  Error on azure-notification-hubs.ts line 12: PushNotification is not defined.